# How to get value for a certain key in multidimentionnal php array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

A certain php array give me this :

```
myarray{
    0=>array { "key_01"=>"value_01", "key_02"=>"value_02"..."key_0n"=>"value_0n"}
    1=>array { "key_11"=>"value_11", "key_12"=>"value_12"..."key_1n"=>"value_1n"}
    .
    .
    .
    n=>array { "key_n1"=>"value_n1", "key_n2"=>"value_n2"..."key_nn"=>"value_nn"}
}
```

And i would like to get this one array:

```
$newarray = {value_01,value_11,value_n1......value_nn}
```

Comment: basically you only want the values and not the keys?

Comment: So loop over myarray, use array_values to get the values of each sub-array in a numerically indexed array, and then merge those with your result array $newarray …

Comment: I believe they just want the value of the first key... value_01, value_11 not value_01, value_02

Comment: yes exactly value_01,value_11,value_n1......value_nn... i'm looking for, extracted from  $myarray.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: @AbraCadaver, i use this $newarray = array_map('current', $array); foreach($newarray as $key => $value){ // trying to list as an array result }...it help me !

Comment: You can accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first value of each sub-array with `current` or `reset`:

```
$newarray = array_map('current', $array);
```

If you need a certain offset (in this case the first) then get the values from each array re-indexed with integers and then extract column 0:

```
$newarray = array_column(array_map('array_values', $array), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Loop through your original array
foreach($myarray as $array){
   // ensures that the keys are in alphabetical/numerical order
   ksort($array);

   // add the first value into your new array
   $newarray[] = reset($array);
}
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver, Jeff Vdovjack  i've tried to use this $newarray = array_map('current', $array);
foreach($newarray as $key => $value){
 // trying to list as an array result
} it help me to a next step..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` to get what you want on each item of your array :

```
$array = array_map(function ($item) { return current($item); }, $array);
```

In your case, this seems to be the first value of the item, so you use `current`.

Reference : https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-map.php